# How to restrict the user to go back previous logged-in pages after press logout

Tags: php, session, session-variables, browser-history

I am working on login functionality....

Now i have the problem... like this

1) After user Press Log-out..

2) if the user clicks the browser back button.. user can see his/her previous logged-in pages...

How can i restrict.. user to go back after log-out...

Everything works fine except this... Help me to fix this..

Here is LoginViewController.php

```
                 <?php  
                      session_start();
                 header("Cache-Control: private, must-revalidate, max-age=0");
                 header("Pragma: no-cache");
                 header("Expires: Fri, 4 Jun 2010 12:00:00 GMT");

                include('GenericClasses/GenericCollectionClass.php');
                include('Models/UsersModel.php');
                include('DataObjects/Users.php');
                include('DatabaseAccess/DBHandler.php');

           if(!empty($_SESSION['user']))
          {
              header("Location:loggedin.php");
               die();
             }
              else 
               {
             ?>
              //Html code for LoginIndexpage
            <?php
             }
              ?>
```

Here is Login.php

```
         <?php
           session_start();
          header("Cache-Control: private, must-revalidate, max-age=0");
          header("Pragma: no-cache");
          header("Expires: Fri, 4 Jun 2010 12:00:00 GMT");

          include('GenericClasses/GenericCollectionClass.php');
          include('Models/UsersModel.php');
          include('DataObjects/Users.php');
          include('DatabaseAccess/DBHandler.php');

         if(!isset($_SESSION['user']))
         {
        header('Location: LoginViewController.php');
           exit();
      }
             echo '<div style="background:white; text-align:right"> Login as:'.$_SESSION['user'].'
      <a href="LogoutViewController.php" style="text-align:right">Logout</a></div>';

       ?>
```

Here is Log-out.php

```
          <?php
        header("Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, max-age=0");
        header("Expires: Sat, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT");
        session_start();
        session_destroy();
           header("Location: LoginViewController.php");
           ?>
```

Any suggestions are acceptable....

Answer (score 1):

Once User get logged in, that time you need to store user id or mail id in session variable.

And You have to put condition on all pages, that if session variable of user id or mail id is set then user can access that page else you have to redirect on Login page.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest checking the `$_SESSION['user']` in every page that requires authentication. This could be implemented using a common Php page that you could `include` in all the pages requiring authentication (which probably will be all except the log-in page). So lets say for example, create a Php page called `Security.php` and inside that page you will have something like the following which was extracted from your question:

```
  if(!isset($_SESSION['user']))
  {
      header('Location: LoginViewController.php');
      exit();
  }
```

Then in every page requiring user authentication, you could include the `Security.php` file at the beginning of the code. Something like this:

```
<?php
    include('YOUR PATH/Security.php');
    //Rest of your code here 
    ...
<?
```

This way, it will not matter if the user hits the back button or if he request the page through the URL input of the browser, if he is not logged in, he will be redirected to the log-in page.

Hope this will help you

Answer (score 0):

Once the user is logged in you have to set a session like `$_SESSION['id']` in inner pages(Dashboard for user)  and you have to put condition on every page i.e:

```
if(!isset($_SESSION['user_id'])){
header("location:login.php")
}
```

This will check the availability of session.Remeber to unset the session in `logout.php`

Comment: How to create session id... I am new to this...sessions

Comment: `$_SESSION['user_id'] = $_POST['userid']` Here user_id in session braces is the keyword for the session

Comment: While i run this .....it's showing some error like "The page isn't redirecting properly"

Comment: `$_POST['userid'];` Are you using the same id

Comment: I am using like this...                                          //If you are submitting the form insert the details into database

    $Username = $_POST['uname'];
    $Password = $_POST['pwd'];
    $User_Type=$_POST['type'];
    $_SESSION['user_id'] = $_POST['userid'];
      
    If (!(empty($Username) && empty($Password) && empty($User_Type))) 
    {
        $model = new UsersModel();
   $rowsCount = $model->checkUser($Username,$Password,$User_Type);
        if ($rowsCount!=0)
        {
            $_SESSION['user'] = $Username;
           header("location:loggedin.php");